# Prevent warning about Macports/Fink installation

Tags: homebrew

How can I prevent the following warning from Homebrew appearing whenever I install something?

> Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
>   Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
>   Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.

Note that I've never (that I recall) installed Fink on this machine and I just uninstalled Macports. I've tried removing /opt/local/bin from my PATH to no avail.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you follow the [official guide](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html)? (specially the "rm" part)

Comment: Yes, that is surely the clean solution, but not everybody works on a single user machine and has admin rights so he can just wipe entire directory structures.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb) (in def macports_or_fink_installed?), it seems to check something like this:

```
$ which port
$ which fink
$ ls /sw/bin/fink /opt/local/bin/port  # if they exist
$ ls -ld /sw /opt/local                # if either directory exists it must be readable
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a dirty hack but if you just want to silence the warning you can comment out the relevant parts of `check_macports` in `$(brew --prefix)/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb`.